# Google Big Query table not able to create using JSON file

Tags: json, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

When creating a table in Google BigQuery using json file uploaded in cloud storage getting below error.

```
Failed to create table: Error while reading data, error message: Failed to parse JSON: Unexpected end of string; Unexpected end of string; Expected key File: GCP_Cloud_Storage_HR_Analytics_POC-Changed_data_14-07[1].json
```

I know we BQ requires New delimited Json file but is there a way to convert JSON to New delimited Json as the record count is more and i can't manually change it

Any help is highly appreciated

To Successfully create a table in BigQuery using JSON file uploaded in Cloud storage

Answer (score 0):

try this code.

It uses ndjson python package which you can install per instructions https://pypi.org/project/ndjson/0.3.1/

```
import ndjson
import json

    # with open('your_input_path_to_json_file/ndjson.json') as f:
    #     data = json.loads(f)
    input = '[{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3},{"x":4,"y":5,"z":6}]'
    data = json.loads(input)
    with open('your_output_path_to_newline_delimted/backup.ndjson', 'w') as f:
        ndjson.dump(data, f)
```

if you don't wish to write a code, try this online converter https://www.json-to-ndjson.app/